# Angular app doesn't work on Firefox after updating it to Version 8

Tags: angular, typescript, browser, polyfills, angular8

We have updated an Angular app from version 7.2 to version 8. The update process has worked so far and the app can be used locally and in prod mode (on the server) on Chrome, Firefox Developer Edition, Safari, Opera as usual.

***But in the normal Firefox browser and Waterfox, the app does not work:***

- The app tries to render while the browser shows the status ***"Performing a tls handshake to localhost"***, until at some point a ***"The connection has timed out"*** comes.
- In prod mode, after I have deployed the app, at least the login mask shows up but the performance of the app is so bad that hardly nothing works.

***We have created a browserlist file with the following content:***

```
# This file is used by the build system to adjust CSS and JS output to support the specified browsers below.
# For additional information regarding the format and rule options, please see:
# https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#queries

# You can see what browsers were selected by your queries by running:
# npx browserslist

> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
not IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```

***Our tsconfig looks like this:***

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "Node_modules / @ types"
    ]
    "lib": [
      "ES2016"
      "Dom"
    ]
    "module": "esnext"
  }
}
```

***And the area with the ssl configuration inside the angular.json so:***

```
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "farm-management-ui:build",
      "port": 8080,
      "ssl": true,
      "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.js"
    },
```

***We have already successfully executed the following commands:***

**ng update @ angular / cli --from 7 --to 8 --migrate - only**

**ng update @ angular / core - from 7 - to 8 --migrate-only**

And I have the feeling that if the app is running in Firefox an endless loop is created, because I can't also open other webpages like Stackoverflow and so on..

Why does Firefox suddenly have this behavior and how can we fix this?

Comment: What is your typescript and node version ?

Comment: @SrishtiKhandelwal Typescript Version 3.4.5 | Node Version v12.4.0 | npm Version 6.9.0

Comment: Try to check if you missed anything. Refer  https://update.angular.io/#7.2:8.0

Comment: I did that 3 or 4 times. Nothing is missing from that guide.

Answer (score 3):

Changing in ***tsconfig.json*** the property `target` from **es2015** to old value **es5**, application works.

Comment: That worked for me, thanks.  I wonder what ES2015 feature FireFox is missing so that is requires a "deeper" polyfill layer?  Is there any negative impact for Chrome and Edge?

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try this command in terminal

> npm i zone.js@latest

After this i can run my app on Firefox

Comment: This also did not work for me.